# How to change location of the Application.groovy class in Grails 3.0.3?

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I've created new application in Grails 3.0.3 using console:

```
grails create-app hello
```

and it's running fine with:

```
grails run-app
```

But now, I would like to change the package name where Application.groovy is located (original location is hello/grails-app/init/hello/Application.groovy) to something else, eg hello/grails-app/init/foo/Application.groovy.
When I'm trying to start application after change there is exception:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class hello.Application
```

Source of the Application.groovy file is (generated by grails, except package name)

```
package foo

import grails.boot.GrailsApp
import grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration

class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }
}
```

Any hints where should I change something to be able to rename this package?

EDIT:
In the documentation there is a fragment:

```
grails-app/init/PACKAGE_PATH/Application.groovy The Application class used By Spring Boot to start the application
```

But still don't know what is PACKAGE_PATH and how to set this.

Comment: If your package statement matches the directory structure then it should just work.  Run `./gradlew clean run`.

Comment: Strange that using `grails clean run` doesn't help, but after executing `./gradlew clean run` now it is working. Now I can run using `grails run`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great.  I am glad you got it to work.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown  if you change your comment into answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your package statement matches the directory structure then it should just work. Run `./gradlew clean run`.

Answer (score 2):

After 2 hours of investigation and based on the Jeff's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583746/how-to-change-location-of-the-application-groovy-class-in-grails-3-0-3/31611925#31611925), here is the detailed explanation:

1. I created a sample app named **foo** which created the `grails-app/init/foo/Application.groovy`
2. I ran the app (using `grails run-app`) and things worked fine
3. Later I changed the package of `Application.groovy` to `com.test` instead of `foo`
4. It failed with error `Could not find or load main class foo.Application`
5. I kept trying `grails clean` and then `grails run-app` but it didn't work because gradle build was not clean
6. I tried setting `mainClassName` or `mainClass` under `build.gradle` but nothing worked

Finally doing `./gradlew clean` made it to work so it is clear that `grails clean` is not actually cleaning the gradle build.

**For windows**, just run `gradlew.bat clean`

Answer (score 0):

I was running it on Win10 and `gradlew.bat clean run` didn't work for me, it said that there is no such gradle task as `run`

what helped me was `gradlew.bat wrapper` which recreated some gradle scripts, and then `grails run-app` worked

Answer (score 0):

And if that still doesn't work, kill your gradle daemons, run a clean again, the re-run.